# Kernel modules with shared register address space

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, linux

I have 1 master and 2 slave kernel modules all of same core functionality and register address space.

I need to write some of the values returned by the slave modules into a register address owned by the master module.

For example:

register 0xF1230000 is a part of master module address space.
I need to write to this register from the slave kernel modules.
I am sure there might be a way to do it.

I am trying to avoid making one single driver for all 3 modules.

Comment: Add a call in the master to write the value.

Comment: Yes, use regmap APIs (there are several of them depending on the needs).